# Change <p> live while typing

Tags: jquery, html, font-face

I'm creating a font tester online. I need people to type on a text input and get their text in a desired font which I'm changing with font-face. I'll change fonts with addClass().

**HTML**

```
<p id="viewer"></p>
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" value="123" />​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.texto').change( function(){    
    var str = $('.texto').val();
    $("p").text(str);
});​
```

This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coffee3k/VeGCy/1/)

Also, is there a something to protect font-face from being downloaded?

Comment: That's nice, what's your question?

Comment: Render the text using the font on the server then display the image, that way the user will never have access to the font.

Comment: Why not use the [`[contenteditable]`](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `#` instead of `.`. `#` is the id selector. `.` is the class selector.

You might also consider using `keydown()` instead of `change()` so the text will update in real time, and not just when they click away from the `input`.

http://jsfiddle.net/VeGCy/9/

Comment: This works on jsfiddle but can't make it to work on the server.

Comment: @coffee Are you putting `onkeydown()` or `keydown()`? `keydown()` is the correct syntax. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Change `$('.texto')` to `$('#texto')`

**Full code:**

```
$('#texto').change( function(){    
    var str = $(this).val();
    $("#viewer").text(str);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VeGCy/3/

Comment: I'd also change the part $("p") to $("#viewer").

Answer (score 2):

> Also, is there a something to protect font-face from being downloaded?

Unfortunately no there is not.  A workaround is to use something like Cufon or Sifr that would convert your text via flash.

You may also be interested in [www.google.com/webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) if you are worried about licensing issues.

Comment: Fonts are all created by me or people working with me. I used font squirrel for the web magic. Maybe some sort of real-time server-side convertion to image?

Comment: If you are going to use images I wouldn't bother using something overly complex to create dynamic images.  Instead create nice images for each of your fonts in photoshop or your image editor of choice and use a phrase that includes all characters of the alphabet and throw in any numbers or special characters your font supports.  This will give you the most control over your font files while still allowing the user to see how your font renders each letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my `#viewer` was lagging behind by one keystroke when using `keydown`.  I fixed this by using the `keyup` method

**Fullcode:**

```
$('#texto').keyup(function(){
  var str = $(this).val();
  $("p").text(str);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VeGCy/9/